# How to extend 1/2" shower connection just a little bit

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I am replacing the shower head we currently have with a new one. The existing shower head used a 1/2" "S" shaped pipe with male threads on each end. The new connection is designed to end up flush with the wall and has just about 3/4" of thread exposed, but the connection inside the wall is in there about 1 1/4". I got a 1/2" male/male nipple and a 1/2" female/female connector, but that ends up being too long - it adds about 2".

Not sure how I can connect this without it being too long or too short. I also don't think I can move the connection inside the wall, as it is attached to the studs, and I don't want to take out tile, etc.

[image: pipe inside wall]

[image: fixture + extension too long]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a one-peice extension fitting that's a bit shorter. Might or might not be shorter **enough;** or too short. You'll probably have to order it or try a comprehensive plumbing supply.

Search on **1/2" pipe thread extension** and you should get results. Male threads on one end, female threads on the other, one solid piece.

The other likely options would be select a different product more adjustable to retrofit installs, or fill the space between the wall and the fitting on a "too long" extension with some sort of accent tile of appropriate thickness.

Comment: Perhaps something like this: https://www.mcmaster.com/4429K298/

Comment: That McMaster Carr part looks like it could work but at 30.11 USD (dollar) plus what ever shipping charge that they will tack on makes it a hard decision to purchase it. This alternate choice https://www.amazon.com/2-pack-Brass-Fitting-Adapter-Female/dp/B079XT6TKK gets you two adapters for just 10.95 USD and shipping can me covered by Prime membership. The hex shape of the Amazon part will be way easier to get a socket on it through the hole in the wall as well.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks y'all.I've just ordered the Amazon parts. Those look like they will work. I'll let you know.